# Looping through dictionary in list from an api call

Tags: python, json, list, api, dictionary

I am currently stuck with the processing of an API call. The all consists of a dictionary in a list.
I am requesting a weather forecast from OpenWeatherMap. The call itself works without a problem, but when i want to extract data from it, it won´t loop through the whole call. The data i can output always stops after the 4th point in the list.

Here is my code which loops through the output:

```
n = 0
for items in data:
    data_list = data["list"][n]
    date_and_time = data_list["dt_txt"]
    wind = data_list["wind"]
    temperature = math.floor(data_list["main"]["temp"] -273.15)


    n += 1

    print(date_and_time)
    print(wind)
    print(f"{temperature} C°")
    print(n)
```

The request.json:

{
"cod": "200",
"message": 0,
"cnt": 16,
"list": [
{
"dt": 1609707600,
"main": {
"temp": 277.97,
"feels_like": 274.32,
"temp_min": 277.97,
"temp_max": 279.11,
"pressure": 1012,
"sea_level": 1012,
"grnd_level": 999,
"humidity": 90,
"temp_kf": -1.14
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 804,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "overcast clouds",
"icon": "04n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 86
},
"wind": {
"speed": 3.15,
"deg": 147
},
"visibility": 10000,
"pop": 0,
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2021-01-03 21:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1609718400,
"main": {
"temp": 277.47,
"feels_like": 274.42,
"temp_min": 277.47,
"temp_max": 277.63,
"pressure": 1013,
"sea_level": 1013,
"grnd_level": 999,
"humidity": 92,
"temp_kf": -0.16
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 804,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "overcast clouds",
"icon": "04n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 93
},
"wind": {
"speed": 2.25,
"deg": 135
},
"visibility": 10000,
"pop": 0,
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2021-01-04 00:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1609729200,
"main": {
"temp": 277.82,
"feels_like": 275.22,
"temp_min": 277.82,
"temp_max": 277.88,
"pressure": 1013,
"sea_level": 1013,
"grnd_level": 999,
"humidity": 92,
"temp_kf": -0.06
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 804,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "overcast clouds",
"icon": "04n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 97
},
"wind": {
"speed": 1.7,
"deg": 111
},
"visibility": 10000,
"pop": 0,
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2021-01-04 03:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1609740000,
"main": {
"temp": 277.39,
"feels_like": 274,
"temp_min": 277.39,
"temp_max": 277.39,
"pressure": 1013,
"sea_level": 1013,
"grnd_level": 998,
"humidity": 94,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 804,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "overcast clouds",
"icon": "04n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 99
},
"wind": {
"speed": 2.79,
"deg": 112
},
"visibility": 10000,
"pop": 0,
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2021-01-04 06:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1609750800,
"main": {
"temp": 278.16,
"feels_like": 275.52,
"temp_min": 278.16,
"temp_max": 278.16,
"pressure": 1014,
"sea_level": 1014,
"grnd_level": 999,
"humidity": 92,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 500,
"main": "Rain",
"description": "light rain",
"icon": "10d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 100
},
"wind": {
"speed": 1.84,
"deg": 87
},
"visibility": 10000,
"pop": 0.23,
"rain": {
"3h": 0.32
},
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2021-01-04 09:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1609761600,
"main": {
"temp": 280.2,
"feels_like": 276.8,
"temp_min": 280.2,
"temp_max": 280.2,
"pressure": 1013,
"sea_level": 1013,
"grnd_level": 998,
"humidity": 83,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 804,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "overcast clouds",
"icon": "04d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 98
},
"wind": {
"speed": 3.07,
"deg": 108
},
"visibility": 10000,
"pop": 0.34,
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2021-01-04 12:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1609772400,
"main": {
"temp": 279.71,
"feels_like": 276.09,
"temp_min": 279.71,
"temp_max": 279.71,
"pressure": 1012,
"sea_level": 1012,
"grnd_level": 998,
"humidity": 85,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 804,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "overcast clouds",
"icon": "04d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 99
},
"wind": {
"speed": 3.35,
"deg": 94
},
"visibility": 10000,
"pop": 0.03,
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2021-01-04 15:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1609783200,
"main": {
"temp": 277.7,
"feels_like": 275.22,
"temp_min": 277.7,
"temp_max": 277.7,
"pressure": 1012,
"sea_level": 1012,
"grnd_level": 997,
"humidity": 90,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 804,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "overcast clouds",
"icon": "04n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 96
},
"wind": {
"speed": 1.41,
"deg": 102
},
"visibility": 10000,
"pop": 0.03,
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2021-01-04 18:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1609794000,
"main": {
"temp": 276.88,
"feels_like": 274.84,
"temp_min": 276.88,
"temp_max": 276.88,
"pressure": 1012,
"sea_level": 1012,
"grnd_level": 997,
"humidity": 92,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 804,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "overcast clouds",
"icon": "04n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 99
},
"wind": {
"speed": 0.66,
"deg": 78
},
"visibility": 10000,
"pop": 0,
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2021-01-04 21:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1609804800,
"main": {
"temp": 276.64,
"feels_like": 274.21,
"temp_min": 276.64,
"temp_max": 276.64,
"pressure": 1011,
"sea_level": 1011,
"grnd_level": 997,
"humidity": 92,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 804,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "overcast clouds",
"icon": "04n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 100
},
"wind": {
"speed": 1.15,
"deg": 278
},
"visibility": 10000,
"pop": 0,
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2021-01-05 00:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1609815600,
"main": {
"temp": 276.48,
"feels_like": 273.97,
"temp_min": 276.48,
"temp_max": 276.48,
"pressure": 1011,
"sea_level": 1011,
"grnd_level": 996,
"humidity": 91,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 804,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "overcast clouds",
"icon": "04n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 100
},
"wind": {
"speed": 1.2,
"deg": 4
},
"visibility": 10000,
"pop": 0,
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2021-01-05 03:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1609826400,
"main": {
"temp": 275.87,
"feels_like": 272.41,
"temp_min": 275.87,
"temp_max": 275.87,
"pressure": 1011,
"sea_level": 1011,
"grnd_level": 996,
"humidity": 92,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 804,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "overcast clouds",
"icon": "04n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 100
},
"wind": {
"speed": 2.45,
"deg": 310
},
"visibility": 10000,
"pop": 0,
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2021-01-05 06:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1609837200,
"main": {
"temp": 277.33,
"feels_like": 273.56,
"temp_min": 277.33,
"temp_max": 277.33,
"pressure": 1012,
"sea_level": 1012,
"grnd_level": 997,
"humidity": 85,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 804,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "overcast clouds",
"icon": "04d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 100
},
"wind": {
"speed": 2.97,
"deg": 300
},
"visibility": 10000,
"pop": 0,
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2021-01-05 09:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1609848000,
"main": {
"temp": 279.21,
"feels_like": 275.72,
"temp_min": 279.21,
"temp_max": 279.21,
"pressure": 1011,
"sea_level": 1011,
"grnd_level": 996,
"humidity": 75,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 804,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "overcast clouds",
"icon": "04d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 100
},
"wind": {
"speed": 2.59,
"deg": 312
},
"visibility": 10000,
"pop": 0,
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2021-01-05 12:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1609858800,
"main": {
"temp": 277.73,
"feels_like": 275.17,
"temp_min": 277.73,
"temp_max": 277.73,
"pressure": 1011,
"sea_level": 1011,
"grnd_level": 997,
"humidity": 81,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 803,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "broken clouds",
"icon": "04d"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 65
},
"wind": {
"speed": 1.17,
"deg": 305
},
"visibility": 10000,
"pop": 0,
"sys": {
"pod": "d"
},
"dt_txt": "2021-01-05 15:00:00"
},
{
"dt": 1609869600,
"main": {
"temp": 277.52,
"feels_like": 275.65,
"temp_min": 277.52,
"temp_max": 277.52,
"pressure": 1012,
"sea_level": 1012,
"grnd_level": 998,
"humidity": 80,
"temp_kf": 0
},
"weather": [
{
"id": 803,
"main": "Clouds",
"description": "broken clouds",
"icon": "04n"
}
],
"clouds": {
"all": 65
},
"wind": {
"speed": 0.1,
"deg": 166
},
"visibility": 10000,
"pop": 0,
"sys": {
"pod": "n"
},
"dt_txt": "2021-01-05 18:00:00"
}
],
"city": {
"id": 2768622,
"name": "Podersdorf am See",
"coord": {
"lat": 47.8541,
"lon": 16.8371
},
"country": "AT",
"population": 1000,
"timezone": 3600,
"sunrise": 1609656103,
"sunset": 1609686737
}
}

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Data is a dict not a list, you iterating the wrong one...

Comment: I don't understand why yoiu use `n = 0` `[n]` and `n += 1`. As for me it gives wrong results. Why not normal `for item in data["list"]:`

Comment: you iterate `data` which has only 4 element `"cod", "message", "cnt", "list"` but you should iterate `data["list"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate wrong element - `data` - which is dictionary and it has only 4 items - `"cod", "message", "cnt", "list"` - and you use `n` to get values from different element - `data["list"][n]` - which has much more elements.

You should iterate `data['list']` instead of `data` - and you don't need `n` for this.

```
data = {....}

for item in data["list"]:
    date_and_time = item["dt_txt"]
    wind = item["wind"]
    temperature = math.floor(item["main"]["temp"] - 273.15)

    print(date_and_time)
    print(wind)
    print(temperature, "°C")
```

Result:

```
2021-01-03 21:00:00
{'speed': 3.15, 'deg': 147}
4 °C
2021-01-04 00:00:00
{'speed': 2.25, 'deg': 135}
4 °C
2021-01-04 03:00:00
{'speed': 1.7, 'deg': 111}
4 °C
2021-01-04 06:00:00
{'speed': 2.79, 'deg': 112}
4 °C
2021-01-04 09:00:00
{'speed': 1.84, 'deg': 87}
5 °C
2021-01-04 12:00:00
{'speed': 3.07, 'deg': 108}
7 °C
2021-01-04 15:00:00
{'speed': 3.35, 'deg': 94}
6 °C
2021-01-04 18:00:00
{'speed': 1.41, 'deg': 102}
4 °C
2021-01-04 21:00:00
{'speed': 0.66, 'deg': 78}
3 °C
2021-01-05 00:00:00
{'speed': 1.15, 'deg': 278}
3 °C
2021-01-05 03:00:00
{'speed': 1.2, 'deg': 4}
3 °C
2021-01-05 06:00:00
{'speed': 2.45, 'deg': 310}
2 °C
2021-01-05 09:00:00
{'speed': 2.97, 'deg': 300}
4 °C
2021-01-05 12:00:00
{'speed': 2.59, 'deg': 312}
6 °C
2021-01-05 15:00:00
{'speed': 1.17, 'deg': 305}
4 °C
2021-01-05 18:00:00
{'speed': 0.1, 'deg': 166}
4 °C
```

Comment: if i use your code, i still get the same output as before:                                                  2021-01-04 00:00:00
{'speed': 2.25, 'deg': 135}
3 °C
2021-01-04 03:00:00
{'speed': 1.7, 'deg': 111}
4 °C
2021-01-04 06:00:00
{'speed': 2.79, 'deg': 112}
4 °C
2021-01-04 09:00:00
{'speed': 1.84, 'deg': 87}
4 °C

Comment: so i am again stuck after 4 entries. I hope this is not a dumb question. I just learned about api calls

Comment: I use my code with your data and get as you see on my aswer. You can't get only 4 items. You had to mess something.

Comment: maybe first check what you get in `data` from server. Maybe you get only 4 items. Or maybe you removed some elements and now you have only 4 elements.

Comment: yeah you are right. i just get those 4 entries when i print data. How is this possible if the API call in the browser outputs me the whole dictionary?

Comment: i found my error. it was with the api call itself. Thank you very much for your time and effort!

Comment: I don't know - maybe you used different function in API - some of them returns only few days, other almost 17 days. Or maybe you use option to get only 4 results.